# How to make a hangman remember your guesses in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

This is currently what I have written:
That is a Hangman Game. After guessing the letter, code should remember previous guess. But it does not.

What changes should I make for this code?

```
import random
word_list = ["aardvark", "baboon", "camel"]
chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)
 
print(f'Pssst, the solution is {chosen_word}.')
 
display = []
for i in range(0, len(chosen_word)):
    display.append("_")
    listToStr = ' '.join(display) 
print(listToStr)
 
end = False
 
while not end:
  guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
 
  result = []
  for letter in chosen_word:
      
    if letter == guess:
      result.append(guess)
    else:
      result.append(display[i])
 
  result = ' '.join(result) 
 
  print(result)
  if "_" not in display:
    end = True
```

Comment: This is because you don't change the `display`. After a guess you should update `display` to  the value of `result` because `result` contains now the current guess.

Answer (score 0):

In your while loop the result array is initialized every iteration.
This means the result is cleared every loop and only the last guess is added to the new empty result array.

Comment: Great. Fixed that. But...

```
Pssst, the solution is aardvark.
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
Guess a letter: a
a a _ _ _ a _ _
Guess a letter: d
a a _ _ _ a _ _ _ _ _ d _ _ _ _
```

then this kind of output comes.